# How to join Array Values as keys to get jSON object value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have been working on a function that loops through a JSON object recursively, and want to use each key it finds as the class value of an element to change the `.text` value of that element in jQuery.  So, far so good, however, as I am able to get the Keys recursively as well, I'm struggling on finding a way to input all of those keys to get each json objects values:

```
function eachRecursive(obj, aKey)
{
    aKey = aKey === null ? '' : aKey;

    for (var k in obj)
    {
        if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null)
        {
            aKey += k + '_';
            eachRecursive(obj[k], aKey);
        }
        else
        {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
            {
                console.log(obj[k]);

                if ($('.player_' + aKey + k).length)
                {
                    var props = aKey.split('_');
                    props.clean("");



                    $('.player_' + aKey + k).text(obj[k]);
                }
            }
            // might not even need this.
            aKey = '';
        }
    }
}
```

So, `text(obj[k])` isn't going to work here since the json is looping through objects inside objects recursively.

So, `aKey` is a string that gets used to check if the class exists (should be appending each key of the json object into it.  Than should check if exists, if it does exist, should plug in the value into the `.text` of that element.

But what I'm sruggling here with is how to get the value from all of the keys that get plugged into an array called, `props`.  So I will need to use each value in the array as keys for `obj` object to get the corresponding json value.

Can someone please help me here?

The `.clean` prototype added to `Array` just simply removes any empty values in the array.  Specifically the last array index (since it splits on `_`).

How to pass array values into `obj` to get the json value?

For Example, if:

```
var props = ['name', 'first', 'last'];

// How to do this so we can get the value?
obj['name']['first']['last'][k]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `props` array and lookup the value in turn using bracket notation.

```
var value = obj;
for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
    value = value[props[i]];
}
value = value[k];
```

Comment: Hello Thank you, but also need to account for when `props` is an empty array, and still need to use `k`

Comment: In which case, just return `value[k]`

Comment: These are `nested` json objects within properties that have keys. You need the entire key depth, all keys in order to get the value.

Comment: And possibly objects within objects. Need the full key structure to get value.

Comment: But you should have already used all the other keys from the `props` array, so calling `[k]` on the result of that should be enough.

Comment: Actually, you're absolutely right, the code I have works just fine...  I'm a moron, didn't even test it before I asked question.  Sorry.  Don't even need `props` array